# Removing whitespaces and leading commas

Tags: java

I want to know how to remove leading whitespaces and empty string in an Array.
so I want the outcome to be: `line 1,line 2,line3 line4,line5`

```
String string="line 1, line 2, , ,   line3 line4,        line 5";
        ArrayList<String> sample=new ArrayList<String>();
        sample.add(string);
        ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String str : sample) {
            if(str!=null && !str.isEmpty()){`enter code here`
                result.add(str.trim());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the array? And what is the outcome you got when you tried that code?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma between line3 and line4? I'm guessing you need to split your input string, then trim each part.

Comment: line 1, line 2, ,,,    line3 line4,        line 5]

Comment: I tried split but it does not work for me i don't know why.

Comment: @java - what problems did you have with `split`, I'm curious, since its the obvious choice here and works.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use a [tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). By additionally [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)ming your strings, you only get the non-empty pieces:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("line 1, line 2, , ,   line3 line4,        line 5", ",");
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = st.nextToken().trim();
    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would user 2 regular expressions this way:

First, remove spaces between commas: replace ",[ ]+," by ",,". Example: "a, , ,  ,b" => "a,,,,b".

Then, remove duplicated commas: replace ",," by ",". Example: "a,,,,b" => "a,b".

Finally use `split` method (in String class) to split the string by ",".
Iterate through this loop doing `trim()` to each token and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
String[] array = 
  "line 1, line 2, , ,   line3 line4,        line 5".trim().split("\\s*,[,\\s]*");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple regular expression. You want to remove all spaces before a comma, and all spaces and commas afterwards. That gives you this:

```
regex.Pattern(" *,[ ,]*").compile().matcher(string).replaceAll(",");
```

Probably you want to have the pattern precompiled in your code rather than recompiling it each time of course.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(string);
    sc.useDelimiter(",\\s*");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String next = sc.next();
        if (!next.isEmpty()) {
              ...
        }
    }
```